# Buttons in NavigationViewItems do not work with incomplete swipe

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a NavigationView which I put a NavigationLink on to another View. The first page with a hidden title. After going to page 2 through Link, everything works at first. I have a title there and 2 navigationBarItems buttons. But if you pull from left to right back to the first screen, but then return (that is, do not go, but only pull a little), then all the buttons stop working. What is the problem?

```
struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                    NavigationLink("View 2", destination: View2())
                }.navigationbarhidden(true)
            }
    }
}
    
struct View2: View {
    @State private var texti: String = ""
    @State var themeColor = Color.green
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TextEditor(text: $texti).padding().onReceive(texti.publisher.collect()) {
                    self.texti = String($0.prefix(2000))}
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title").navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack { Button(action:{}) {
                Text("Fund").foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058824, green: 0.6901960784, blue: 0.4588235294, alpha: 1)))
            }; Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Gust").foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058824, green: 0.6901960784, blue: 0.4588235294, alpha: 1)))
            }})
}
```

Comment: Ignore minor bugs in your code. I copied it incompletely.

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: This works if you don't hide the first title. What if he is hidden?